# Count number of pods without using kubectl if Amazon CloudWatch Container Insights with Enhanced Observability is installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-eks, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have deployed Amazon CloudWatch Container Insights with Enhanced Observability with EC2 in my eks cluster. Without running kubectl from commandline, I need to to find the status of the pods and the count of each type of pod (number of pods with same name) so that I can raise an alarm whenever the number of pods becomes less than a certain minimum threshhold.

How should I do this? I am not able to find any metrics that gives this number directly. A lambda function that checks the cloudwatch logs might work as well, but not sure what to check in the logs with it.

Could some one help with getting the answer for this if possible with code.

Comment: Is this sort of test? What are you trying to achieve because you can use deployments in k8 to achieve minimum number of pods

Comment: Under some circumstances the connectivity to artifactory (from jfrog) breaks and we want to be warned with an alarm to slack/sms when eks is not able to download container images from there during scaling events.

Comment: Can someone still help me: I found some relevant metrics, however I am unable to get the metrics from the container insights with enhanced observability add on aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace AWS/EKS --metric-name pod_status_running --start-time "$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ --date '-24 hour')" --end-time "$(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ)" --period 86400 --statistics Sum --dimensions Name=ClusterName,Value=myclustername command                     pod_status_failed
pod_status_ready
pod_status_running
pod_status_scheduled
pod_status_unknown
pod_status_pending